# Ошибка: CS7036 Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "x" из "Vector.Vector(int, int)"

Tags: c#

```
class Vector
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Vector(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public static Vector operator +(Vector V1, Vector V2)
        {
            return new Vector { X = V1.X + V2.X, Y = V1.Y + V2.Y };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Здравствуйте господа, только начал практиковаться в С# и в процессе написания класса Vector столкнулся с такой ошибкой. До этого было много других ошибок в процессе написании кода, которые я порой не без труда решал, но к этой даже не знаю как подступить. Чувствую, что ошибка глупая, но догадаться не выходит.

Comment: Да, ошибка весьма глупая. Вы в классе переопределили конструктор, требуя через него `int x, int y`, но при создании этого класса вы почему то этот конструктор всячески игнорируете, хотя должно быть `new (1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не использовали конструктор. У вас идёт инициализация свойств, а конструктор сам без дела.

Т.е. можно было сделать так

```
Vector v = new Vector(5, 3); // инициализация конструктора 
return v; // возвращение объекта
```

Если говорить о инициализации свойств или полей класса, то в данном случае можно делать так:

```
Vector v = new Vector(5, 3); // конструктор
v.X = 7; // инициализация public int X {get; set;}
v.Y = 4; // инициализация public int Y {get; set;}
return v; // возвращаем объект v
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ошибка даже глупее чем я думал.

Comment: @Bathory на начальных этапах это ваш опыт, относитесь к этому спокойно :)